# glob expansion suddenly not working properly in loops

Tags: command-line, bash, rm

I am trying to run:

```
for i in *; do sudo rm $i; done
```

The problem is that there is something wrong with glob expansion and I get the error:

```
rm: cannot remove '*': No such file or directory
```

I get this error for each time that the loop runs. The files *are deleted* (even though I used CTRL+C to stop the errors) but I am getting this error that I should not get as I did not escape the glob symbol and I did not use any single quotation marks.

This has always worked in the past without the error.

Also, if I run:

```
sudo rm 1*
```

for example, it will run use the glob properly. However, if I run:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do sudo rm $i*; done
```

I get the following:

```
rm: cannot remove '1*': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '2*': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '3*': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '4*': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '5*': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '6*': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '7*': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '8*': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '9*': No such file or directory
```

What is wrong with my globs in loops now?

I am not interested in different methods of deleting the files. I am only interested in what is wrong with glob expansion. Glob expansion seems to work (all the files are deleted) but then it wants to loop again like I escaped the glob character instead of being done.

---

EDIT:

It seems this is only a problem when there is an excessively large number of files. I ran the command: `for i in *; do sudo rm $i; done` on the same directory with only 800 files and I could not reproduce the error.

I also tested the command: `for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do sudo rm $i*; done` and I did not get an error when only deleting ~800 files and some numbered dummy files.

Comment: Please explain better why exactly you need a loop there – “there are too many files to delete in one `rm` command”?

Comment: My problem is not that I need to delete these files. The problem is that I have always used globs in this exact loop for this exact purpose and I never got an error until now. Also, I just realized that it actually does delete the files but it seems that it wants to throw the `rm: cannot remove '*': No such file or directory` error for each deleted file which doesn't make sense. Now that the directory is empty, I still get the error one single time. I even get the error when running `sudo bash -c 'for i in *; do rm "$i"; done'`. The shell is performing glob expansion but then it is also not.

Comment: Could it be that you have `set -f`/`set -o noglob`?

Comment: @guillermochamorro No, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It seems this is only a problem when there is an extremely large number of files.  I ran this command on the same directory with only ~800 files and it would not reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

"too many files to delete in one `rm` command." - is a problem with a well-known solution - use `find` and `xargs`. Together they handle "too many files" as well as "files with funny characters". Read `man find` and `man xargs`.

Your particular case, "`for i in *; do sudo rm $i; done`" would be expressed as

```
find . -maxdepth 0 -type f -print0 |\
    xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty sudo rm
```

will run as few `sudo rm` commands as it can, stuffing as many filenames as it can on a line (see `xargs --show-limits </dev/null` ).

Or, one could

```
sudo find . -maxdepth 0 -type f -delete
```

but tastes vary.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the loop is possibly behaving this way only on an extremely large number of files. I tried my loops on a smaller number of files in the same directory and I did not get the error. I really wasn't looking for an alternative method to delete the files. However, it seems that the limits of `rm` may be causing this error and loop behavior (even though the files are deleted).

Comment: Any background about _why_ "too many files to delete in one `rm` command" is a thing? How many is too many?

Comment: In the control block (metadata) of a process, there's a fixed size command buffer. It's not the number of arguments, it's the combined length. That's why `/proc/<PID>/cmdline` works (`man proc`). That's why I suggested `xargs --show-limits </dev/null`, as the actual limits can vary across systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you need `sudo` to remove anything in this directory, you most certainly don’t have read permissions either, which prevents `bash` from performing the glob expansion – run your loop in a root shell instead:

```
sudo bash -c 'for i in *; do rm "$i"; done'
```